# cassandra opscenter dashboard does not show Backup tab,

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have installed `OPScenter` and added a 3 node cluster for management. I am trying to schedule backup of keyspaces using `opscenter` but the backups tab under data is not enabled. Also as per the documentation the data Backup tab is not there in the Dashboard page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kamal

Answer (score 1):

Are you hooking opscenter to DataStax Enterprise or Apache Cassandra? Some features of Opscenter will only work with DSE, while others will work with both.

Comment: Thanks for your response . I am using community version of DataStax. Version is 2.1.0.

Comment: Advanced features are only in DSE... Community versions won't have all the features on opscenter.

Comment: You can also look into Talena (www.talena-inc.com) for backup of Cassandra databases (and other Big Data platforms like Hadoop, Vertica, Couchbase, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I am using DSE v4.8, OpsCenter v5.2.4, still cannot see the backups tab in 'Data' section of the OpsCenter.

Never mind, it has been moved to the 'Services' section. Some of DataStax's documentation is not up to date.